# Delete folders of latest 6 months with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this folders, based on date:

```
- 2015/12
- 2016/01
- 2016/02
- ...
- 2016/11
- 2016/12
```

Now, in a task on my Ansible Playbook I want to synchronize these folders from a remote server to another.

My problem is that I want to synchronize only the latest six months, so 2016/06 until 2016/12 and ignore the other folders. The same will be in some months or next year, so I need something dynamic.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take last six values from your list, you can use this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    mylist:
      - 2016/01
      - 2016/02
      - 2016/03
      - 2016/04
      - 2016/05
      - 2016/06
      - 2016/07
      - 2016/08
      - 2016/09
      - 2016/10
      - 2016/11
      - 2016/12        
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Take only last six {{ (mylist | sort)[-6:] }}"
```

Comment: What if we'll be in June 2017?